# Counting proof of choosing

Tags: combinatorics

I'm doing an exam review without any solutions. I don't know why this is true.

$$ ∑_k^n 5^k\binom{n}{k}  = 6^n$$

Comment: is the lower index of $k$ not specified or is it $k=0$? Also, do you just need to prove the equality, or are you to specifically do it combinatorially?

Comment: Did you want a counting proof, as the title indicates, or an algebraic proof, as your acceptance indicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you mean $\sum_{k=0}^{n}5^{k}\binom{n}{k}=6^{n}$.

Be aware
that in general: $$\left(a+b\right)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a^{k}b^{n-k}$$
What comes out if $a=5$ and $b=1$?

Comment: Ohh okay, that makes sense now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the correct choice for the index $k$... Hint: $5+1=6$ + Newton's B = answer.

Answer (score 0):

$6^n$ is the number of ways to assign the numbers $1$-$6$ to $n$ items.

$\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways to choose $k$ items from $n$

$5^k$ is the number of ways to assign the numbers $1$-$5$ to $k$ items.

To assign the numbers $1$-$6$ to $n$ items, choose $k$ items to be assigned $1$-$5$ then assign the rest $6$. This gives
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}5^k=6^n
$$